# Is there a way i can launch another program without having to do a fork()?

Tags: c, fork

I have a main program written in C, i need it to launch another process in parallel,
I used the function

```
system("./server");
```

the problem is that this process contains a while(1) loop so it never return to the main application...

Is there a way i can launch the program without having to do a fork()?

thanks!

Comment: You need to specify what the second process needs to do - especially what it shares with the main caller. Does it get input from "launcher"? Will it have to return a value or a set of values? Are there any potential locking or competition issues between the two? Can the launcher ask the subprogram to quit before it completes?

Comment: What is the problem with `fork()`?

Comment: I guess it's because fork is not available on win.

Comment: Can you elaborate why fork() isn't an option?

Comment: i'm working on an application that consumes about 0.7%memory (i checked with top) and it would be too much to fork() it and have  1.4% memory used...

Comment: It won't double the memory used. When you first call `fork`, the memory will be shared. You will immediately be calling some form of `exec`, which will replace the process entirely. (And, by the way, `system` calls `fork` to create the new process anyway.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure - just do this:

```
system("./server &");
```

Answer (score 5):

In UNIX/Linux `fork()` (usually folowed by `exec()`) is the only way to create a new process.

All other ways (`system()`, some OSes have `spawn()`) really use `fork()`.

So `fork()` is just unavoidable (for UNIX/Linux).